# Is any built in control available in DevExpress for changing FontColor like Microsoft word having?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I need to add the control like Microsoft Word having to change the FontColor. Attached the image the below to show what i need to know whether the Devexpress already having any control related to this ???

[image]

Please let me know the suggestion on this.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using an XtraRichEditControl, you can use the ColorEdit control. You can use its EditValueChanged event to code your font color changing logic.  The control will not display a "A" with a underline color, but you can override the CustomDraw event to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.